# how to prevent multiple events on fast mouse moves?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to fade between two images when mouse is on, and when mouse leaves the element. This creates some inproper transitions when mouse moves too fast. How to prevent that?

My code:

```
$('.prods li').live('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).children('.label').stop().animate({top: '80%',opacity: 1}, 800, 'easeOutQuint');
    if ($(this).children('.producthover').length) {
        $(this).children('.product').fadeOut(800);
        $(this).children('.producthover').fadeIn(800);
    }
}).live('mouseleave',function() {
    $(this).children('.label').stop().animate({top: '50%',opacity: 0}, 800, 'easeOutQuint');
    if ($(this).children('.producthover').length) {
        $(this).children('.product').fadeIn(800);
        $(this).children('.producthover').fadeOut(800);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `.stop()` to `.stop(true,true)`?

Comment: worked :) please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing `.stop()` to `.stop(true,true)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for intent.

Basically you need to delay the execution of the animation so as to make sure another action has not taken place within that minimum time.

```
var mouseEnterTimer = null;

$('.prods').on('mouseenter', 'li',  function(){

   /*clear timer since another mouseenter has occured within 200 ms */
   clearTimeout(mouseEnterTimer); 


   /*now queue up another one to execute 200 ms later*/
   mouseEnterTimer = setTimeout)function(){
      //all your animation logic here

   }, 200); 
});
```

This ensures that the event is fired **only once** even if the mouse is rapidly moved in and out of the area in question.

---

You may want to read further about [debouncing events](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/). (and how they are [different from throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/))

Also, there already is an excellent [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)(among others).